# Canonical not updating after adding trailing slashes

Tags: magento-1.9, seo

I'm in the process of trying to add trailing slashes to all of the pages of the site. I managed to get it working with by adding the suffix to the products and categories from the settings.

I have added some htaccess to manage the 301's to the trailing slashes.

My issues are:

1. For some reason, this doesn't add it to the homepage. I couldn't find where to add this
2. Also, the canonical tags were pointing at the non-trailing slash URL.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can realize this only with the suffix setting and `.htaccess` rules.

I've done it the other way around (redirect URLs with trailing slash to URLs without trailing slash) using an observer for CMS, category and product controllers:

```
<?php
/**
 * integer_net Magento Module
 *
 * @category   IntegerNet
 * @package    IntegerNet_Seo
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2016 integer_net GmbH (http://www.integer-net.de/)
 * @author     Fabian Schmengler <fs@integer-net.de>
 */
use Varien_Event_Observer as Event;

class IntegerNet_Seo_Model_Observer_Redirect
{
    /**
     * @see event controller_action_predispatch_catalog_category_view
     * @see event controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view
     * @see event controller_action_predispatch_cms_page_view
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $event
     */
    public function redirectUrlWithSlash(Event $event)
    {
        if (! Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('catalog/seo/redirect_urls_with_trailing_slash')) {
            return;
        }
        /** @var Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action $controller */
        $controller = $event->getData('controller_action');
        $requestUri = $controller->getRequest()->getRequestString();
        if (substr($requestUri, -1) === '/') {
            $urlWithoutSlash = Mage::getUrl('', ['_direct' => trim($requestUri, '/')]);
            $controller->getResponse()->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=86400', true);
            $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($urlWithoutSlash, 301);
            $controller->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            $controller->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::FLAG_NO_POST_DISPATCH, true);
        }
    }
}
```

You should be able to use that and adjust it to add a missing slash instead of removing it.